# schedule an Void action with alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i want to schedule an `action` for a time period say between 2 pm - 8 pm to be execute once everyday when user opens the app and for that i am trying to use `alarmManager` but am not sure is a good idea for accomplishing my goal or not am trying this :

```
    Intent mintent = new Intent(getActivity(), TabFragment4.class);
// here i am creating an intent and tabFragment4 is this class (where am setting this intent)
    mintent.setAction("Set", showCallbacks());
//here am trying to put Action which is showCalbacks but it didn't seems to work cause its not the proper way of doing this and am not able to figure how to add action properly 

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, mintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//here is my pending intent 

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 01); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
//here am setting my calendar's time for 1 pm 

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//here am creating AlarmManger named am

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent );
//here am scheduling my action for repeating everyDay
```

my Function which  i want to schedule for executing at only once (but everyDay)

```
    public void showCallbacks() {
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .title("Hey")
            .content("ballin in the budget ?")
            .positiveText("Yeah")
            .negativeText("Neah")
            .neutralText("")
            .onAny(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), (which.name() + "!"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            .show();
}
```

my approach is good enough ? and if yes than please help me for putting this action into alarmManager and if  my approach is not what it really takes than please guide me so that i can achieve what i want thanks :) any guidance will be so helpful for me , thanks

my broadCastReciever class:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);



}
```

}

ps - if my question is not clear enough than please let me know i'll fix it

Comment: You have to put this method inside Your onReceive() method from the BroadcastReceiver that gets triggered if alarm starts....

Comment: hey @Opiatefuchs firstly thanks a lot ,  can you give some details in deep ?

Answer (score 2):

If You want to set alarm at perticular class than you can use Broadcast Receiver and alerm Manager.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

> In MainActivity

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

        info.setText("\n\n***\n"
                + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: by seeing your code i think that i have to declare my intent and schedule it inside my void `showCallBacks()` am i right ?

Comment: If you want to show your dialog at perticular time than your dialog must be put in onReceive method of broadcast receiver class

Comment: the whole dialogue right ? ad after putting it there i have to schedule it as your answer ??? the `IN MAINACTIVITY` one

Comment: No, You can´t show a dialog inside a receiver....don´t do that, Your app will crash.....